# Delay for get request to basehttpserver on Ubuntu server

Tags: python, ubuntu, get, virtual-machine, basehttpserver

My problem...

1. We have a local network.
2. i run a python basehttpserver on a virtual machine with Ubuntu Server(12.04.2).

When i open in browser link 192.168.101.3:8081/index.html, get request processed 10 seconds, why??

example basehttpserver

```
class ReqHandler( BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def __init__(self, request, client_address, server):
        BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler.__init__( self, request, client_address, server )

    def do_GET(self ):
        self.performReq(self.path.decode('utf-8'))  

    def performReq (self, req ):
        curDir = os.getcwd()
        """ Performing http request """
        if req == '/' :
            self.path = '/index.html'
        fname  = curDir + '/' + self.path[1:]   
        fname = unquote(fname).decode('utf8')
        try:
            self.send_response(200,"Ok!")
            self.send_header('Content', 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8' )
            self.end_headers()
            f = open(fname, 'rb')
            self.wfile.write(f.read())  
            f.close()
            print 'file '+fname+" Ok"   

        except IOError:
            print 'no file '+fname  
            self.send_error(404)

def run(server_class=BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer):
    server_address = ('', 8081)
    server = server_class(server_address, ReqHandler)
    print('server ok!')
    server.serve_forever()
```

screenshot from server 
[image: log server]

IP machine with ubuntu server 192.168.101.3

Sorry for my English.

My solution - I added the following method in ReqHandler

```
def log_message(self,fmt, *args):
    print fmt%args
```

Comment: Profile your code with fabulous python "profile" library, that will tell you what and why: http://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html

Comment: I am having the same issue with a basehttpserver on OSX. I am making a simple GET request to retrieve a single document from mongodb. The request stays delayed for around 10-20 seconds each time. The chrome console shows status "Waiting" during this time. Any other request like POST or PUT are completing in milliseconds. Also, GET requests to external sites are working as normal, so I definitely don't think the client is the issue. Please share if you find a solution and I'll do the same.

Answer (score 3):

If your testing your webapp on a local network not connected to Internet, you may encounter these delays. It is because BaseHTTPServer is performing by default a lookup on the client IP (for logging purpose). Check this hack: http://bugs.python.org/issue6085